# Scrapy response.follow query

Tags: scrapy, response

I followed the instructions from this page http://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('span small::text').get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

The above example works for their pages

```
<ul class="pager">
<li class="next">
<a href="/page/2/">Next <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;/span></a>
</li>             
</ul>
```

I now want to change the response.follow to search a page which contains some links in this format

```
Page 1
<div class="pages-list">
<ul class="page">
<li class="page-current">1</li>
<li class="page-item"><a title="Page 2" href="/url2">2</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a title="Page 3" href="/url3">3</a></li>

Page 2 and so on
<div class="pages-list">
<ul class="page">
<li class="page-item"><a title="Page 1" href="/url1">1</a></li>
<li class="page-current">2</li>
<li class="page-item"><a title="Page 3" href="/url3">3</a></li>
```

and tried different variations to get the next page starting from the first page

I cannot see anything wrong but my code only checks the first page and then stops

```
next_page = response.css('li.page-current a::attr(href)').get()
```

or

```
next_page = response.css('li.page-current li a::attr(href)').get()
```

Both don't work, please advise, after page 1, will want to check page 2, then page 3, etc.

Comment: What about using extract() instead of get()?

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. is there a way to do a for lop and run it on url?page=1. url?page=2 etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy with XPath:

```
next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="page-current"]/following-sibling::li[1]/a/@href').get()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it didn't work. No error message but was just ignored ?

Comment: @Web_Developer Please show your **real** code: there is no _current page_ on `http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/`

Answer (score 0):

Try : `relative_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href').get()`

In scrapy shell that gives : 
'/page/2/'

Also:
You can use urljoin to concatentate with http://quotes.toscrape.com if need be, as follows:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
domain = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com'
           url = urljoin(domain, relative_url)

And then use the url variable as per :

yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse)
```