# Unable to go next page

Tags: python, css, xpath, pagination, scrapy

Trying to scrape the internet archive website **(Wayback Machine)**: https://web.archive.org/web/20150906222155mp_/https://www.zalando.co.uk/womens-clothing/.

I am succesful in scraping the 1st page content, but can't move to the next page. I have tried multiple `xpath` to move to next pages:

```
# 1
 next_page_url = response.xpath("//li[a[contains(.,'>')]]//@href").extract_first() # does not work
# 2
next_page_url = response.xpath(//a[@class='catalogPagination_page' and text() ='>'])[1]//@href).get() # does not work
```

I have tried converting to `absolute url` (and without) but again with no luck.

Can anyone help with new `xpath` or `css selectors` that I can finally `scrape` the next pages?

Below you can see my full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
class ZalandoWomenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zalando_women_historic_2015'
    allowed_domains = ['www.web.archive.org']
    start_urls = ['https://web.archive.org/web/20150906222155mp_/https://www.zalando.co.uk/womens-clothing/']

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath("//a[@class='catalogArticlesList_productBox']")
        for product in products:
            link = product.xpath(".//@href").get()
            absolute_url = f"https://web.archive.org{link}"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_url,callback=self.parse_product,dont_filter=True,meta={'link':link})
        # process next page 
        next_page_url = response.xpath("//li[a[contains(.,'>')]]//@href").extract_first() #(//a[@class='catalogPagination_page' and text() ='>'])[1]//@href
        absolute_next_page_url = f"https://web.archive.org{next_page_url}"
        #absolute_next_page_url = next_page_url
        #absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_next_page_url,callback=self.parse)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        link = response.request.meta['link']
        brand = response.xpath("//span[@itemprop='brand']/text()").get()
        price = response.xpath("//span[@class='price oldPrice nowrap']/text()").get()
        price1 = response.xpath("//span[@itemprop='price']/text()").get()
        price2 = response.xpath("//div[@class='boxPrice']//span[contains(@class,'price')]/text()").get()
        disc_price = response.xpath("//span[@class='price specialPrice nowrap']/text()").get()
        
        product_type = response.xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']/text()").get() 
        material = response.xpath("//div[@class='content']//li[contains(.,'material')]/text()").get()
        yield {   
            'brand_name': brand,
            'product_price':price,
            'product_price1':price1,
            'product_price2':price2,
            'product_price_b4_disc':disc_price,
            'link':link,
            'product_type':product_type,
            'material':material}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
next_page_url=response.xpath(".//a[@class='catalogPagination_page' and text() ='>']/@href").get()
```

Will get : *'/web/20150906222155/https://www.zalando.co.uk/womens-clothing/?p=2'*

You can then use split("/") to remove the "/web/201509..." bit

Note 1: I used the " " quotes inside the parentheses.

Note 2: in Scrapy you can also use "response.follow" to save having to join a relative URL to a base URL.

Check this post as well:
[Scrapy response.follow query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741674/scrapy-response-follow-query#57742423)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Question, why would I remove the first part that says 'web/201509...'? I think that is part of the URL as the website I am trying to scrape is an internet archive website.

Comment: What I mean is that, that specific part of the URL indicates at what point in time I am accessing the website. So removing that, we will be going to the current version of that website.

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't realise you only wanted the archive.

Comment: I tried it with your ```xpath```, but unfortunately it does not work. Any further ideas on why?

Comment: I just tested it in scrapy shell and it worked fine.

Comment: Do you have response 200? If so, have you copied my code exactly, as you need to make sure you have "" and '' in right places.

Comment: Yeah I copied and pasted it exactly as you wrote it. Did you try it on your machine and it scraped all the pages??

Comment: It's quite slow, I had one error 302, but eventually it loaded page 3, (obviously it'll need to load page 3 from the response from page 2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225668/discussion-between-sophods-and-dr-pi).

Comment: On scrapy shell, it works for me aswell, like I can see the correct @href. When I try to scrape the data and place it into csv using VScode, it does not work.